# How to join with the max date of second table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables and now I want to join them on user_id and date but the date of the second table should be the max date for that user but before the current date.

Table 1

```
date       | user_id | purchase
2020-01-01 |1        |10
2020-01-05 |1        |13
2020-01-11 |1        |15
```

Table 2

```
date       | user_id | cumulative_items
2019-02-02 | 1       | 1
2019-06-05 | 1       | 2
2019-10-12 | 1       | 5
```

Desired Table 3:

```
date       | user_id | purchase | cumulative_items
2020-01-01 |1        |10        | 5 
2020-01-05 |1        |13        | 5
2020-01-11 |1        |15        | 5
```

How do I do this in Snowflake SQL partition on user-id and date?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a ```qualify``` after the join - ```QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date desc) = 1```

Comment: SELECT t1.date, t1.user_id, t1.purchase, t2.cumulative_items
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date  < t1.date
WHERE t1.user_id = 1
ORDER BY t2.date DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: @IvoP This solution is good but it does not return all my results from t1 due to the limit clause i think. I edited my t1 to show how it should return. could you please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if have a couple of CTE for the tables:

```
with table_1(date, user_id, purchase) as (
    select * from values
        ('2020-01-01'::date, 1, 10),
        ('2020-01-05'::date, 1, 13),
        ('2020-01-11'::date, 1, 15)
), table_2(date, user_id, cumulative_items) as (
    select * from values
        ('2019-02-02'::date, 1, 1),
        ('2019-06-05'::date, 1, 2),
        ('2019-10-12'::date, 1, 5)
)
```

we can then do a normal join on `user_id` being equal and the t1 date being more recent than t2

```
select t1.date, t1.user_id, t1.purchase
   ,t2.*
from table_1 as t1
join table_2 as t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.date > t2.date
```

| DATE | USER_ID | PURCHASE | DATE | USER_ID | CUMULATIVE_ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 2019-02-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 2019-06-05 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 13 | 2019-02-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 13 | 2019-06-05 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 13 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 15 | 2019-02-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 15 | 2019-06-05 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 15 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |

then we can take the single most recent via a ranking function (rank, dense_rank, row_number), here we choose row_number as we only want one result per input, and we put that into a qualify.

```
select t1.date, t1.user_id, t1.purchase
   ,t2.*
from table_1 as t1
join table_2 as t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.date > t2.date
qualify row_number() over(partition by t1.date, t1.user_id order by t2.date desc) = 1
```

gives:

| DATE | USER_ID | PURCHASE | DATE | USER_ID | CUMULATIVE_ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 13 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 15 | 2019-10-12 | 1 | 5 |

now clean up the selection:

```
select t1.date, t1.user_id, t1.purchase
   ,t2.cumulative_items
from table_1 as t1
join table_2 as t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.date > t2.date
qualify row_number() over(partition by t1.date, t1.user_id order by t2.date desc) = 1
```

| DATE | USER_ID | PURCHASE | CUMULATIVE_ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 13 | 5 |
| 2020-01-11 | 1 | 15 | 5 |